# Disable form error displaying

Tags: forms, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I add helper to display form errors above form, but how can I disable form displaying when echo $form is called?

Why so basic tasks are so difficult in Symfony 1.4? :(

Comment: You are working with the admin generator or normal module generator?

Comment: normal module generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way is to remove manually the instructions like

`<?php echo $form['myfield']->renderError() ?>`

from the form template generated in `apps/myapplication/modules/mymodule/templates`. Very annoying I know.

Maybe, thinking out loud, you could try to add a `css` rule to hide error messages inside your form:

`ul.error_list li { display:none; }`